# Streaming Camera Data to Separate Application

Tags: ros, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am in the process of building an application where I would like to embed the Gazebo simulation environment only into my application and then run non-interactive ROS modules on it. It seems like I should be able to acquire frames from the camera like in the tutorial [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.0/plugins/camera_plugin) and then pipe them elsewhere for display. Does that seem like a feasible way to approach the problem? I don't want to get too deep into hacking and find out what I'm doing isn't viable at all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1783/streaming-camera-data-to-separate-application/) by [crypticstar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/204/crypticstar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That is one way of doing it.

The other way is to subscribe to the image topic from your application. This will require your application to compile against gazebo though. Find the topic using `gztopic list` in command line.
This [example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/70c7d23fd53e/examples/stand_alone/listener?at=default#) shows how to subscribe to a topic, and [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/70c7d23fd53e9df59123c0698c918814c0203a57/gazebo/gui/viewers/ImagesView.cc?at=default) (line 120 and line 145) shows you how to get the image data from the msg.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1